# Compiler Warning... Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation'?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings

In Xcode I get a warning in the following line for FBConnect:

`_orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;`

This is the full warning:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation'
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is too vague. If you can, can you add some details.

Comment: Oh heres the line of code where the warning is: _orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try changing

```
_orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

to

```
 _orientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Comment: statusBarOrientation return UIInterfaceOrientation instead of UIDeviceOrientation. The casting seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
UIDeviceOrientation _orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```